# Can a phone battery be used to power Arduino or Motors

Tags: arduino, batteries, dc-motor, charging, cellphone

I was wondering whether it would be possible to use a rechargeable battery from an ordinary cell phone to power some electronics such as a motor shield for Arduino?
Can that be done and if yes then how?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very unlikely that a cellphone battery can power a motor shield, assuming motors will be actually operated off it. Motors typically draw large currents, and while modern Lithium-Ion batteries have fairly high current rating, they are designed to supply just enough for a small portable device.

There are however very low-current motors available, such as pager motors, which can be run from a cell phone battery.

If the objective is only to run an Arduino board and conceivably a shield, but not operate a motor, things begin to look more positive.

Success would depend on the specifics of the cell phone battery, but in general:

- Many recent cell phones use Lithium-Ion batteries, with a nominal voltage of **3.7 Volts**. This is insufficient for running any of the 5 Volt Arduino models, or any motor shield that I am aware of. This voltage can be used with some 3.3 Volt Arduino and clone boards: Not all 3.3 Volt Arduino boards support an input lower than 5 Volts, though.
- The battery itself must allow power to be drawn from its contacts, without any special handling: Some cell phone batteries require a resistor of a specific value range connected between two of the tabs, to enable power delivery. Others *may* require (no specific example comes to mind) an electronic dialogue with the host cellphone, to enable charging / power delivery.
- Some older cellphone batteries supply a 5 or 5.5 Volt output (I wonder what battery chemistry they use). Such a battery will be better equipped to power a 5 Volt Arduino and similarly various 5 Volt shields.
- Many cellphones contain a battery management circuit, used for controlled charging, battery monitoring and power delivery management. Bypassing this is not a good idea: Some types of battery will be damaged without battery management, or may no longer hold charge if drained beyond a point.

How this can be done:

- Identify the positive and terminals of the battery (many have more than 2 terminals) and measure the voltage with a voltmeter. No reading = this battery isn't going to work.
- Connect the above-mentioned 3.7 Volt compatible Arduino and the shield(s) to the two identified battery terminals.
- Make sure the battery is recharged before it gets fully depleted.

---

If the devices to be operated do not support 3.x Volt supplies, a boost regulator circuit can be used to boost the battery voltage to 5 Volts, with 75 to 90% efficiency.

This will work, but the current delivery capability of the boost regulator will be lower than that of the battery alone.